# How to count how many words/sentences are repeated in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of names (column A), but it can be a column of sentences too.
How can I count how many times that word/sentence is repeated in the column?

Here's an example:

[image]

Would the `COUNTIF()` help in this scenario? Any help is appreciated

Comment: What if the name Maria appears twice in a sentence? Or the sentence contains the name Mariam? I think more complicated sample data would be helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

Here's an example we'll replicate

[image]

In Column D3, I typed Maria. In column E3, I typed `=COUNTIF(B:B, "*" & D3 & "*")`

That means, if `*Maria*` was found in column B, count it. `*` is a wildcard. It doesn't matter what's before or after `Maria`. If D3 contains `Maria`, count it.

Then, in column D4, type Carlos. Copy the formula from E3 to E4.

Then, in column D5, type Anna. Copy the formula from E4 to E5.

You can even change B4 from Carlos to Armando and you'll see Carlos' count go down to 0.

You can add `What is Anna doing?` under `Who is Maria` and you'll see Maria's count go up by 1.

Comment: `"What is Mariam doing?"` contains Maria. Maria's count goes up by 1. If OP has a use case where the name `Maria` and exactly that noun should be searched in columns, I'd have to think of a different solution.

Comment: Is there a way to only count of if it matches specifically? For example Name `Who is Maria` will go up 1 since it's counting the whole sentence, but `Maria` will remain at 4

Comment: Yes, @tadm123. That is how it currently works. In the name column, under Anna, if you type `Who is Maria` and copy the formula from Anna down to `Who is Maria`, you will get 1 for `Who is Maria` and `Maria`'s count will remain 4.

Answer (score 0):

Using ADODB is easy to COUNT grouping by column.  Pass as parameter the destination cell to start the copy
of the result.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub sqlNamesCount(Optional destination As Range = Nothing)
   Dim connection As Object, recSet As Object, sql As String
   
   sql = "SELECT [F1], COUNT([F1]) FROM [SHEET07$P2:P14] GROUP BY [F1] ORDER BY [F1]"
   Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   With connection
      .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
      .Open
      Set recSet = .Execute(sql)
   End With
   If Not destination Is Nothing Then
      Call destination.CopyFromRecordset(recSet)
   End If
   recSet.Close
   connection.Close
   Set recSet = Nothing
   Set connection = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]